# Employee-number as PK, some employees have to wait for their number

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, primary-key

I'm dealing with the following problem.

Company has many employees, all receive a unique employee number once their contract is entered into the system. Sometimes the contract is delayed and the employee starts before they have an employee number.

Department of the company needs a database with more details about their employees. This is needed as soon as they start. So I have a perfect primary key in that it's an unique integer company wide, but sometimes it's not there yet. What is the best practice here?

Storing them with a temporary number in the same place is out of the question, the PK should be immutable.

Personally I was thinking of storing the employee data in a separate table with an autoincremented PK and query this table with the rest of the tables when it's not empty. Once the employee receives it's number, it will get removed from this table and added to the main table. This somehow seems a better option to me than adding another unique identifier to every single employee because of 1 outlier every once in a while.

Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any harm in having an autoincrement number for everyone, and it'll be a way easier approach than the separate table.

Comment: use a surrogate PK....

Comment: I think you need to fix your business processes to address the issue that departments need employee ids as soon as they start.  The on-boarding process should start *before* the start date, and assigning an employee id should be part of that process.  I wouldn't jump through hoops in the database, when it is the process that needs to be fixed.

Comment: The PK should NOT be the employee number. To my way of thinking, internal ids should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This would have been my preferred solution as well. Sadly this is the situation I have to deal with and I have no influence in changing it.

Answer (score 3):

You're making it overly complicated.

> Company has many employees, all receive a unique employee number once their contract is entered into the system.

Give them a number as soon as you have any of their information. If they need a different number later on (for some sort of badge number, etc.), add a field that holds it, however the initial internal ID should never change or be updated.

Comment: > however the initial internal ID should never change or be updated

Yes I understand, I stated this myself as well.

After reading your comment and the others I realised using a surrogate key is the way to go, also because it's value is anonymous compared to the employee number, something I didn't think about before.